# SQL Server: get records that their date is either begining or end of the month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
ID     Website     Artticles_Count      Date
---------------------------------------------
1     example.com        150          2012-05-1
2     example.com        190          2012-05-2
3     example.com        219          2012-05-3
.
.
.
30     example.com        4350         2012-05-30
31     example.com        4432         2012-05-31
32     example.com        4503         2012-06-1
```

I want to show a history of the article counts in a long period (2-3 years). as the record count would be a lot I want to show a summery and retrieve Ariticles_Count value of begining and end of each month. in the example table shown above 150 and 4432 must be retrieved for May 2012.

Can any one help me with the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to assign a number to each row in a month.  Then you can group on the month, and use `max(case ...` to pick the first and last entry for that month:

```
select  website
,       year(date)
,       month(date)
,       max(case when rn_asc = 1 then Artticles_Count end) as FirstOfMonth
,       max(case when rn_desc = 1 then Artticles_Count end) as LastOfMonth
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by year(date), month(date)
                    order by date) rn_asc
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by year(date), month(date)
                    order by desc) rn_desc
        ,       *
        from    Artticles
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        website
,       year(date)
,       month(date)
```

Comment: I'm curious that you picked aggregates instead of a WHERE clause (e.g., `WHERE 1 IN (rn_asc, rn_desc)`). That way, no aggregate is needed, and you'd also be able to include other columns from the selected rows.

Comment: @ErikE: Thanks for the edit, much appreciated.  The question asks for the last and first count in a single row.  To get there you have to pivot somehow, and aggregates are one way to do that.

Comment: It's perfectly valid, of course! I was just curious if you had a particular reason. The ability to include other columns made it seem to me a natural choice to avoid aggregates here. But no biggie! Ironically, my answer uses aggregates, too, (though in a way that lets me still include other columns). :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what format you expect to receive the result in. Here's my attempt:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,Website varchar(20) not null, Artticles_Count int not null, Date date not null)
insert into @t(ID,Website,Artticles_Count,Date) values
(1 ,'example.com',150 ,         '20120501'),
(2 ,'example.com',190 ,         '20120502'),
(3 ,'example.com',219 ,         '20120503'),
(30,'example.com',4350,         '20120530'),
(31,'example.com',4432,         '20120531'),
(32,'example.com',4503,         '20120601')

select Website,YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date),
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(day,-1,Date)) != MONTH(Date) THEN Artticles_Count END) as MonthStart,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(day,1,Date)) != MONTH(Date) THEN Artticles_Count END) as MonthEnd
from @t
where MONTH(DATEADD(day,-1,Date)) != MONTH(Date) or
MONTH(DATEADD(day,1,Date)) != MONTH(Date)
group by Website,YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date)
```

Which produces:

```
Website                                      MonthStart  MonthEnd
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
example.com          2012        5           150         4432
example.com          2012        6           4503        NULL
```

(We don't have a month end figure for your June data)

The above may not, however, perform well - you need to let us know if it doesn't perform well enough for you. The reason it won't perform well is that it precludes the use of indexes. An alternative formulation can be built where we use a reasonable starting month and a numbers table to generate a CTE that contains all month start/end dates, which could then be used in a join that might be able to leverage an index - if one exists.

The above does have one benefit - it's reasonably easy to see what it's doing.

Comment: This would work if there are no missing entries.  I think you can remove the `where` entirely

Comment: @Andomar - that's true. If probably overthought this one (although if we wanted to switch to the one that may benefit from an index, we would want some form of selection criteria)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

```
select website, Date, 
    f.Artticles_Count FirstCount, 
    l.Artticles_Count LastCount
from your_table f
   join yourtable l 
      On Day(f.Date) = 1
          And l.Date = DateAdd(day, -1, DateAdd(Month, 1, f.date))
Where date Between @startDate And @EndDate
```

This approach assumes there is only one record in this table for each website on each date

Answer (score 1):

Here's another working strategy:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
   *
FROM
   dbo.Artticles A
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN Date IN (
      Max(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Year(Date), Month(Date)),
      Min(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Year(Date), Month(Date))
   ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c32f0/1)